# Two folders in the file system as one virtual folder in the path of the site address (web server in Go)

Tags: go

I have two folders in the file system "files1" and "files2".

I can host one folder in the file system as one virtual folder in the path of the site address like this:

```golang
http.Handle("/public/", http.StripPrefix("/public/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./files1"))))
```

How can I host the contents of the "files1" and "files2" folders on the same path of the site address "/public/" ?

Comment: Decide how to handle file name collisions, then take the code from http.FileServer and modify it to serve two folders.

Comment: Or, save yourself a bunch of hassle and *don't bother*.  serve 2 folders or put the contents in one folder

Comment: @erik258 "Thank you", you gave an answer of this kind: - Guys, tell me how can I fill gasoline in my car. - You don't need to refuel it, just push it with your hands to where you want to go.

Comment: @WayMax Please be friendly and respectful. I don't think ridk258 meant anything bad. In my opinion, this is a reasonable suggestion. Workaround should be the last one to consider. We should try to make a system as simple as possible at the first place. (tip: you can delete your comment if you would like to ^_^).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution is to implement the [http.FileSystem](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#FileSystem) interface.

Here is the demo:

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "io/fs"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/public/", http.StripPrefix("/public/", http.FileServer(mergedDir{
        Dir1: "./files1",
        Dir2: "./files2",
    })))

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

type mergedDir struct {
    Dir1 http.Dir // Dir1 will be tried first so it has higher priority.
    Dir2 http.Dir
}

func (d mergedDir) Open(name string) (http.File, error) {
    f, err := d.Dir1.Open(name)

    if err != nil {
        if errors.Is(err, fs.ErrNotExist) {
            return d.Dir2.Open(name)
        }
    }

    return f, err
}
```

I have tested with this directory structure:

```
├── files1
│   ├── f1-1.txt
│   └── f1-sub
│       └── f1-s.txt
└── files2
    ├── f1-1.txt
    ├── f2-1.txt
    └── f2-sub
        └── f2-s.txt
```

There are two `f1-1.txt`, the one in `files1` is served because `files1` is tried first.

---

**Update**:

Another version of `mergedDir` to support multiple directories as requested by the author:

```golang
type mergedDir struct {
    Dirs []http.Dir
}

func (d mergedDir) Open(name string) (http.File, error) {
    for _, dir := range d.Dirs {
        f, err := dir.Open(name)
        if err == nil {
            return f, nil
        }
        if !errors.Is(err, fs.ErrNotExist) {
            return f, err
        }
    }

    return nil, fs.ErrNotExist
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for your reply. But could you tell me if it is possible to implement this code in another way? My idea is that the "files1" folder is always "mounted" as "my.site.com/public/" and the "files2" folder may or may not be "mounted" in some cases. And the number of such folders is not fixed, there may be folders "files3" and others. I would like to be able to add them to "my.site.com/public/".

Comment: Can you elaborate this part `the "files2" folder may or may not be "mounted" in some cases`? I think it's doable. But I don't understand what exactly you want. Maybe add a flag to the `mergedDir` struct and change the implementation of the `Open` func to check this flag?

Comment: I apologize for not explaining well. I don't know English and I use an online translator. I would like something similar:

func addMount(httpDir string, fsDir string) {
<...>
}

addMount("/public/", "./files1")
if <...> { addMount("/public/", "./files2") }
if <...> { addMount("/public/", "./files3") }

Comment: See the bottom of my updated answer. I think it should work for you. Use it like this: `dirs := []http.Dir{"/files1"}; if <...> {dirs = append(dirs, "files2")}; if <...> {dirs = append(dirs, "files3")}; dir := mergeDir{Dirs: dirs}`

Comment: Thank you very much. This is not quite a solution (I would like to not have a single "point" of combining folders, but to be able to add them separately), but maybe I can adapt your code myself. Thank you very much again.